# SoftRAID array not visible to apps on boot?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, raid, mdadm

My `/` is located on a single SSD, but I also have a softraid for my apps, games, etc. Most notably, both my Steam library and my Dropbox folder are located on the raid array.

Whenever I boot my system, these apps don't seem to be able to see their respective folders on the raid array unless I first browse the raid array in Nautilus to at least the base level.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to stop this happening, so the apps can immediately on startup see the folders they need?

EDIT:

`fstab` output:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=454daf70-785f-4887-aa02-8998e0ae819b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=346b9234-0246-40cf-a7f1-bd630ad178dc none            swap    sw              0       0
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/bcb7c4d3-574e-43f0-9f73-658ab99652c4 /mnt/bcb7c4d3-574e-43f0-9f73-658ab99652c4 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Is it normal to be missing an entry for md0 (the raid array)?

Also as requested...
`df` output:

```
root@MAXWELL:/etc# df -hTa
Filesystem     Type             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
sysfs          sysfs               0     0     0    - /sys
proc           proc                0     0     0    - /proc
udev           devtmpfs         3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
devpts         devpts              0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs          tmpfs            797M  1.3M  796M   1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4              48G   18G   28G  39% /
none           tmpfs            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           fusectl             0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none           debugfs             0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
none           securityfs          0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
none           tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs            3.9G   67M  3.9G   2% /run/shm
none           tmpfs            100M   80K  100M   1% /run/user
none           pstore              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
binfmt_misc    binfmt_misc         0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
systemd        cgroup              0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
gvfsd-fuse     fuse.gvfsd-fuse  0.0K  0.0K  0.0K    - /run/user/1000/gvfs
/dev/md0       ext4             1.8T   62G  1.7T   4% /media/alistair/apps
gvfsd-fuse     fuse.gvfsd-fuse     0     0     0    - /root/.gvfs
```

`blkid` output:

```
root@MAXWELL:/etc# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="454daf70-785f-4887-aa02-8998e0ae819b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="346b9234-0246-40cf-a7f1-bd630ad178dc" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="3e05ec7a-7639-ede0-f10a-479bb9aa5f56" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0: LABEL="apps" UUID="f9e0cb41-0eec-4711-849b-b6264496e7be" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="e5dd8df4-1984-9909-9dd0-c27944b24ccc" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="5147b7a9-ff6f-8fd0-0a67-f5be2c6d2ae2" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sde1: UUID="287eb6bc-c874-7858-71fd-92f103f0b7ab" UUID_SUB="814353c9-6b9e-621d-0f13-d05845264b33" LABEL="MAXWELL:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
```

Comment: Do you mount that device through `/etc/fstab` or automagically? In doubt post your `/etc/fstab` and browse to the mount point, and then execute as `root` the commands as follows and post their output.  `df -hTa` and `blkid`

Comment: Original post edited with the requested info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a static mount point entry in `/etc/fstab` which is OK if the RAID array is always available during boot, e.g. the disks are not removable media like USB plugged disks. Otherwise the boot process may stall or fail.

You also need to create a folder to mount the RAID array to. Best would be to not use `/media` or any subfolder because that is used by automagically-mount processes like `udev` rules and could thwart your mount.

So, I would recommend...

```
mkdir -p /data/apps
```

Then add the entry to your `/etc/fstab`.

```
UUID=f9e0cb41-0eec-4711-849b-b6264496e7be /data/apps               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       2
```

Then unmount the raid and mount it at the new mointpoint.

```
umount /media/alistair/apps
mount -a
```

Then you also should check if the `/dev/md0` device is still getting mounted when you try to access `/media/alistair/apps` which could lead to problems and we have to check how to disable that.